# How to upload 3 files with 3 internet connection to ftp?

Tags: c#, networking, interface, video-streaming, load-balancing

I have to stream video with 3 internet connection bonded
1st step i split video into seconds files
2nd step i need to upload every second using different gateway
3rd step i merge seconds files

My problem how to choose the specify network card to upload specify file in C# language

Answer (score 0):

Normally you don't need to care about which network card is used. If one card has a public IP and the second one a private IP the internal traffic will go over this card and traffic to the internet to the card which has a gateway.

Comment: i have 3 gateways and need to upload 3 files first file upload via gateway 1, second file via gateway 2 and last one via gateway 3